# How to know from which country people are accessing my website?

Tags: 7, log-messages

I am using Drupal7. I have a Chinese version of my site and I want to know whether they are using it or not. So I want to know which countries are using my website.

I tried to find that out like this -> if I go to the Reports>>Recent Hits then I find the hostname for the anonymous users.

I found some website that tells the country name taking the host IP address as input.

Is there any module that shows country from which the website got accessed?

Comment: Do you want to *know* that (then @4life answered already, or be able to use that in your scripts, like displaying "free pizza near %yourarea"?

Comment: Actually I have a Chinese version of my site and I want to know whether they are using it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a module for that. Simply make use of any web analytics system such as
 [Google analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), [Piwik analytics](http://piwik.org/) and such like.

Comment: Just to make sure... can I include this in my website? Maybe a page which shows a pie chart of % usage in countries ?

Comment: @Dan - I asked in comment under your question do you want to **know** the data or to **use** it in your site. There you said you wanna know. Please decide. But to answer your concern - yes, you can import GA data to Drupal. Not the easiest thing, but it can be done. "How" is a matter for separate question.

Comment: ya i just want to know the stats. so 4life's answer is what i need.